# Drawing Kagome lattice

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been looking for a package to draw different lattice types. For example, I need to draw the `Kagome lattice`.[image]

What could be the best way to draw this structure? Also, is there any dedicated package to draw different types of lattices?

Comment: TikZ and some \foreach loops could take care of it.  Or just TikZ and OCD.  Somewhjat related: http://www.elfsoft2000.com/bs/fractal.pdf

Comment: A search of this site shows a similar but different question: [drawing a decorated honeycomb lattice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656538/drawing-a-decorated-honeycomb-lattice) which might help as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not-very-efficient way to do this is with some nested for-loops, just drawing hexagonal nodes with circular nodes at each vertex.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric, calc}

\tikzset{
    my hex/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=1cm},
    my circ/.style={draw, circle, fill=blue!50!white, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1.5mm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \foreach \n[count=\k] in {3,4,5,4,3}{
    \foreach \m in {1,...,\n}{
      \node(h)[my hex] at (-\n/2+\m,{\k*sqrt(3)/2}){};
      \foreach \t in {1,...,6} \node[my circ] at ($(h)+({(\t-1)*60}:.5)$){};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```